# Why aren't jasmine-reporters / jasmine-xml2html-converter doing anything? (Protractor)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, protractor, jasmine-reporters

This isn't making any reports happen at all. Can you see the reason why? Thanks!

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
    return capsPromise.then(function(caps){
        var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName;
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: false,
        savePath: 'C:/QA/test_results/'
    }));
},
```

// A callback function called once tests are finished.

```
onComplete: function() {
    var path = require("path");
    var browserName, browserVersion;
    var reportPath = 'C:/QA/test_results/';
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
    return capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
        browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toLowerCase();
        browserName = browserName.replace(/ /g,"-");
        browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
        return null;
    });

    var HTMLReport = require('jasmine-xml2html-converter');
        reportPath += browserName;
```

// Call custom report for html output

```
testConfig = {
    reportTitle: 'Test Execution Report',
    outputPath: reportPath,
    seleniumServer: browser.seleniumAddress,
    applicationUrl: browser.baseUrl,
    testBrowser: browserName + ' ' + browserVersion
};
new HTMLReport().from(reportPath + '/junitresults.xml', testConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your onPrepare function stops when reaching a "return" statement. Actually the addReporter function is never called.

You should add your jasmineReporter **then** storing your browser capabilities. Try something like this :

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: false,
        savePath: 'C:/QA/test_results/'
    }));

    return browser.getCapabilities().then(function(caps){
        var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName;
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an change in the cap_method in latest selenium servers. Try something like this:
 instead of:

```
return capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
    browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toLowerCase();
    browserName = browserName.replace(/ /g,"-");
    browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
    return null;
});
```

Use this:

```
  browser.getCapabilities().then(function(c){
    console.log(c.get('browserName'));
    browserName = c.get('browserName').toLowerCase();
    browserName = browserName.replace(/ /g,"-");
    browserVersion = c.get('version');
    return null;
});
```

I am able to generate html from xml however, testbrowser value in the html shows 'undefined'.